# A grid layout with size, defined by size of its cells and gap

Tags: html, css, flexboxgrid

I have the following layout:

```
<div class="mygrid">
  <div class="first cell"></div>
  <div class="second cell"></div>
  <div class="third cell"></div>
  <div class="fourth cell"></div>
</div>
```

The styles are:

```
.mygrid
{
  background-color: gray;
  display: grid;
  gap: 1px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);
    grid-template-areas:
        'first      second'
        'third      fourth';
}

.cell
{
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

(Here's [the sample](https://codepen.io/sergevdev/pen/vYrByrr) on CodePen).

I expected the grid container (`div.mygrid`) would have column width and row height defined by maximal dimensions of the cells, because I set them as `repeat(2, auto)`. So, the total size would be `81px` x `81px` (`40px` * 2 + `1px` of gap). But it actually has the same width as its parent.

How to achieve the described behavior?

Also, when I explicitly set the size of `div.mygrid` (`width: 200px;`), the `gap` property is ignored and the cells are distributed evenly. Why and how to fix this?

Comment: inline-grid instead of grid ?

Comment: `display: inline-grid;` instead of `display: grid;` seems to fix your problem according to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677972/make-parent-expand-to-the-width-of-child-with-display-grid

Comment: @TemaniAfif @ChenBr `display: inline-grid;` solves the first problem, thank you! But how to solve the second? When I set width manually, for instance `200px`, the gap (`1px`) is ignored.